# Inline function as template argument, without using function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inline

I'm developing an object Foo, which have several member variables and one major member function bar().

```
template<typename T>
Foo
{
public:
    T bar()
    {
       ...
       return m_a + myfunction(m_b);
    }

private :
    T m_a, m_b;
};
```

At the moment myfunction is another member function. But I would like to be able to write a main like this :

```
float newfunction(float) {....}

void main()
{
    Foo<float, newfunction> foo;
    float result = foo.bar();
}
```

And so, newfunction would be used inline in bar() instead of myfunction. I don't want to use a function pointer for performance purpose :  bar() use openMP and myfunction() is designed to be called thousands times per second by each core of the cpu. And so I think that in this condition, my function must be inline and I must not use a pointer. And newfunction is a simple function, with a really low computational cost.

Comment: Please measure before making assumptions about performance. I really doubt that calling a function pointer is the bottleneck in *any* code.

Comment: In fact, bar() use openMP and myfunction() is designed to be called thousands times per second by each core of the cpu. And so I think that in this condition, my function must be inline and I must not use a pointer.

Comment: You should really measure it though. Your function probably does a lot of stuff, and the overhead of calling a pointer is very low compared to the overhead of the function.

Comment: No, myfunction is a very simple function for example It could be just a sum or a product.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use `newfunction` in the `Foo::bar` function, then I suggest you pass it as an argument to the `bar` function instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename F>
    T bar(F func)
    {
        return m_a + func(m_b);
    }

    T m_a, m_b;
};
```

Then you can call it like

```
Foo<float> foo;
float result = foo(newfunction);
```

---

If on the other hand you need to store the function to be used in multiple member functions of `Foo` I recommend you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Then you can do something like

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::function<T(T)>& func)
        : m_function(func)
    {}

    T bar()
    {
        return m_a + m_function(m_b);
    }

    T m_a, m_b;
    std::function<T(T)> m_function;
};
```

To be used as

```
Foo<float> foo(newfunction);
float result = foo.bar();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for something fixed at compilation time. I don't want to use pointer.

Comment: @Nodera *Why?* What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Do you want `constexpr` functions? Because otherwise, function calls will happen at runtime anyway, even if "inlined". Perhaps you should take some time to read about [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and think about how you can improve your question to tell us the *actual* problem you want to solve with this particular solution.